# Genesis Rabbah (ch. 1 "On Creation") available online?

Tags: sources-mekorot, internet, midrash, creation

Do any of you know if Genesis Rabbah's first chapter ("On Creation") is available online? Would you mind directing me to the source?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94 is all of it

Comment: @DoubleAA, sounds like an answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: Yes, I agree, that looks like a great source too.

Comment: Does anyone know why this question would be marked down? I thought you can ask for research advice on locating a source? It makes me worry every time I post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the **Genesis Rabba Online Menukad** from [Torat Emet online](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01633.html), you can also find the **Yalkut Shim'oni** in wikitext and [in atar Daat](http://www.daat.ac.il/he-il/tanach/midrashim/yalkut-shimoni/). B"H nowadays Tora Munachat Bekeren Zavit, Kol harotse Yavo Veytol.